# Finding the palindrome of a number in c

Tags: c, palindrome

This code don't give me the right answer and i couldn't find the mistake. How can i fix the code?

Scenario: First it determines number's number of digits and then palindromes the number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int number=42321,j=0,dig,temp;
    long long pal= 0LL;

    temp=number;     
    while(temp>0)
    {
          temp/=10;
          j++;
    }

    while (number>0)
    {          
          dig=number%10;
          pal+=dig*(int)pow(10,j);
          number/=10;
          j--;  
    }

    printf("%d",pal);
    getch();   
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to debug the code ?

Comment: What should be the answer for `42321`? What about `42323`

Comment: If you have to ask stackoverflow this question for a job interview test, you're probably not going to be able to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
while(temp>0)
{
      temp/=10;
      j++;
}
```

you are computing the number of digits that `number` has, that's one more than the exponent of the highest power of ten not exceeding `number`. You need to decrement `j` after that.

But using `pow()` is not the best way, far better is to construct the reversed number incrementally:

```
while(temp > 0)
{
    pal = 10*pal + temp%10;
    temp /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined `pal` as `long long`. Afterwards you lied to the compiler telling it you would be passing a value of type `int` but sending `pal`: a value of type `long long`

```
    printf("%d",pal); /* WRONG */
```

Don't do that.
Use the proper conversion specifier

```
    printf("%lld", pal); /* preferred */
```

or cast the value to the proper type

```
    printf("%d", (int)pal); /* UGH! */
```